# Razor view claims property doesn't exist while it does on model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my model `UserViewModel`:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Favorite> Favorites { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote these lines in my User view:

```
@foreach (var lessonItem in Model.Group.Lessons)
{
    foreach (var favoriteItem in Model.Favorites)
    {
    }
}
```

And the result is this:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: '`Moalem.UI.Web.Models.UserViewModel`' does not contain a definition for '`Favorites`' and no extension method '`Favorites`' accepting a first argument of type '`Moalem.UI.Web.Models.UserViewModel`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is wrong there?

Comment: post begining of your view file, there is `UserViewModel` declared as `Model` and it's possible that `UserViewModel` does not contain `Favorites` check it

Comment: on user class you got group property twice

Comment: Did you specify the model type in your view?

Answer (score 4):

Your User view, which you did not show entirely, seems to declare at the first line:

```
@model Moalem.UI.Web.Models.UserViewModel
```

You also didn't show this `UserViewModel`, but I guess it has no property named `Favorites`.

If you show all *relevant* code, perhaps more useful answers can be given.

---

Further questions according to your edit: what does the `@model` on top of your view say? What is the namespace of the `UserViewModel` you posted? Are there any other errors, does the project containing the model compile successfully? Unless you're doing something really really special (which you aren't), the compiler is always right. The problem is in your code.